# How do i split a string of hexadecimal into groups of 2 and convert to binary using javascript

Tags: javascript, binary, converters

Recently I found this code that converts Hexadecimal into binary but the problem now is the string input has to be in follow format "ff ff ff ff"instead of "ffffffff"

I am trying to create a method to seperate "ffffffff" into "ff ff ff ff" at the same time convert it to binary.

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    return ("00000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
}

var a = "ffffffff".match(/.{1,2}/g);
alert(a);


var result = ""
"ff ff ff ff".split(" ").forEach(str => {
    result += hex2bin(str)
})
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.match()` is returning an array of `["ff", "ff", "ff", "ff"]` so you could pass that directly into the `forEach()`.

Another optimization would be to use `reduce()`, like this:

```js
function hex2bin(hex) {
  return ("00000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
}

var bin = "ffffffff".match(/.{1,2}/g).reduce((result, hex) => result += hex2bin(hex), "");

console.log(bin);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `match()` function is doing what you require, you just need to work with the array it returns:

```js
function hex2bin(hex) {
  return ("00000000" + (parseInt(hex, 16)).toString(2)).substr(-8);
}

var result = "ffffffff".match(/.{1,2}/g).map(str => {
  return hex2bin(str)
}).join('');

console.log(result);
```